# Combinatorics Problem - Clients using two seperate services

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A financial group offers personal insurance and stock trading brokerage services. In total 10,000 people use their services. The group has 7,000 clients who use the insurance service and 5,000 who use the stock trading brokerage service.

a) If we know that a client uses the stock trading brokerage service then what is the probability that he/she uses the insurance services too?

b)If we know that a client uses the insurance service then what is the probability that he/she uses the stock trading brokerage service too?

c) Is the event that a client uses the insurance service independent from the event that he/she uses the stock trading brokerage service? Explain your answer using the results in parts a) and b).

Thank you for the help, I'm really lost with this one!

EDIT: When trying to answer a) I did: P(I)=0.7, P(S)=0.5, P(InS)=0.35. I then did P(InS)/P(I) to get 0.5, it seems wrong to me since that is the same as P(S).

Answer (score 1):

Your basic mistake was to assume independence at start.

$P(I \cup S) = P(I) + P(S) - P(I \cap S)$

$1 = 0.7 + 0.5 - P(I\cap S)$, so $P(I\cap S) = 0.2$

The rest should easily follow !

Comment: It makes sense now to me that they are not independent, I would just like to check: would the answer for a) be different than the answer from b)? I'm not sure if I'm going about this wrong, but if I were to just do P(S∪I) = P(S) + P(I) - P(S∩I), I get 0.2 again.

Comment: Of course, the two will be the same ! Draw a two circle Venn diagram . Interchanging the order in which you write I and S doesn't change a thing !